# Бот дискорт, список пользователей и сравнение с гугл формой Python

Tags: python, discord

Буду благодарна, если подскажите, как мне лучше сделать.

Хочу получить список пользователей из дискорт.
Чтобы я не делала выходят только боты в чате:

```
 import discord
client = discord.Client()
token = ''
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    users = client.users 
    print(users)
    #or
    guilds = client.get_guild        
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
client.run(token)
```

Выводит только ботов. Везде проставила галочки Privileged Gateway Intents.
Но все равно только ботов дает.

Второе, не могу дойти как мне интегрировать гугл шитс с дискорт. Задача в том чтобы бот смотрел список участников, брал ник и сравнивал с ником в гугл шитс, если он такого находит, смотрит если у него определенное количество баллов, присваивается роль.

Я связала в питон гугл шитс. Вопрос вот как мне проходится по спискам.

Comment: ```intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!